# How can I debug executables for Windows using GDB in WSL?

Tags: windows, debugging, gdb, nasm

I'm frankly not even sure if this is a thing GDB can do, but no amount of searching I've done so far has given me a 'yes' or 'no'.

When I attempt to debug an application using a GDB installation built for Linux and opened in WSL, it is unable to insert a breakpoint anywhere in the program, claiming it can not access the memory at that address. If I do this from Windows with a GDB built for Windows, this error does not happen (and before you ask why I don't just use the Windows build, it's because I'm having other miscellaneous issues with that one. I may open a question for that as well)

I've got an internal error from GDB as well, but unfortunately, I can't seem to recreate it right now.

I've tried rebuilding GDB, as well as switching to another version of GDB (the same as my Windows build)

I'm using a WSL installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and GDB 10.2, configured as follows:

```
(gdb) show configuration
This GDB was configured as follows:
   configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
             --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --without-expat
             --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/local/share/gdb (relocatable)
             --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/local/lib/gdb (relocatable)
             --without-libunwind-ia64
             --without-lzma
             --without-babeltrace
             --without-intel-pt
             --without-mpfr
             --without-xxhash
             --without-python
             --without-python-libdir
             --without-debuginfod
             --without-guile
             --disable-source-highlight
             --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/local/lib/debug (relocatable)
```

To see if this was an issue with the particular program I was debugging, I made a very minimal program in NASM (my original project was also in NASM) and compiled it as follows:

```
nasm -f win32 -gcv8 Test.asm
gcc -m32 -g Test.obj -o Test.exe
```

The source assembly is very simple. It just calls `printf` with a string and integer.

```
; Test.asm
    global      _main
    
    extern      _printf
    
    section     .data
fmt:    db      "%s, %d", 0x0
string: db      "Testing...", 0x0

    section     .bss
num:    resd        1

    section     .text
_main:
    mov dword   [num], 28
    
    push dword  [num]
    push        string
    push        fmt
    call        _printf
    add     esp, 12
    
    ret
```

When attempting to debug this with GDB in WSL, this is the output I get:

```
(gdb) file Test.exe
Reading symbols from Test.exe...
(gdb) set architecture i386:x86-64
The target architecture is set to "i386:x86-64".
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401520
Starting program: /mnt/c/NASM/Test.exe
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x401520
```

EDIT: After poking at it some more, I discovered something that seems important. GDB is only unable to access the memory and place breakpoints when the program is running. Before I've started the program, I can place breakpoints and disassemble freely.

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00401520 <+0>:     mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x405028,0x1c
   0x0040152a <+10>:    push   DWORD PTR ds:0x405028
   0x00401530 <+16>:    push   0x40300b
   0x00401535 <+21>:    push   0x403004
   0x0040153a <+26>:    call   0x40249c <printf>
   0x0040153f <+31>:    add    esp,0xc
   0x00401542 <+34>:    ret
   0x00401543 <+35>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x00401545 <+37>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x00401547 <+39>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x00401549 <+41>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x0040154b <+43>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x0040154d <+45>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x0040154f <+47>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *main+26
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40153a
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/c/NASM/Test.exe
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x40153a
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00401520 <+0>:     Cannot access memory at address 0
```

EDIT 2:
I don't know how useful this information might be, but I did find a method that consistently causes an internal error for GDB. Starting execution of the program, then setting the architecture to `auto` causes an internal error every time I've tried it.

```
(gdb) file Test.exe
Reading symbols from Test.exe...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401520
Starting program: /mnt/c/NASM/Test.exe
warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x401520

(gdb) set architecture auto
warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
/mnt/c/Users/Joshua/gdb-10.2/gdb/arch-utils.c:503: internal-error: could not select an architecture automatically
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

If the answer to this really is as simple as "GDB built for Linux can't debug applications built for Windows"... I'll be very sad, and also quite annoyed that I was unable to find that info anywhere.

Comment: So you're trying to debug a Windows executable with a gdb for Linux? I'm surprised this even gets so far. And also, you build a 32bit executable with `gcc -m32`, and then override gdb to set it to 64bit with `set architecture i386:x86-64`, what's that about?

Comment: @ssbssa Unfortunately, yes, that's what I'm trying to do. The GDB build for windows was having... many strange issues that I found even harder to search for. I genuinely believed I would get further doing this. The override is because GDB complains about it being built for i386:x86-64. Why? I have no idea. It's not a 64 bit program.

My thinking in regards to using the Linux build is "it's the same debugger, I won't be surprised if it supports the same debugging functionality". I know it's a strange combo, but at least this has a consistent failure. My issues with windows GDB is inconsistent

Comment: Even if it's a consistent failure, I don't think this combo is even supposed to work. I would be interested to know what your issues with windows gdb are, because I use it a lot without any big problems.

Comment: @ssbssa I have two issues that happen randomly when I launch GDB for Windows. Sometimes output does not get colorized (which I could deal with, but I'd really rather not because colors help me so much to understand the wall of text at a glance), and sometimes TUI refuses to open because "Cannot enable the TUI when output is not a terminal" even though the program does use terminal output?? I thought that using GDB with WSL would be a better way to go because the issues for Windows appear and disappear with each launch of GDB. If I can't get anywhere with this q, I'll open another one.

Comment: Aren't these 2 issues the same? I get both of them when I use gdb from the MSYS2 terminal, but that's expected, because they aren't a "real" windows console. But with cmd.exe this should never happen.

Comment: @ssbssa Nope! Sometimes I get one without the other, and sometimes I actually get two variations on the "no color" problem. Sometimes the regular GDB output doesn't colorize but I can enable TUI and TUI *is* colorized. Sometimes neither gets colorized. Sometimes normal output is colorized but TUI isn't. And sometimes I have color but can't enable TUI. All of these are CMD, and it doesn't matter if I launch it from a batch file or manually from a command line. Maybe you see why I thought WSL might be better? It's ludicrously inconsistent with Windows, and inconsistency is hard to debug/fix.

Comment: I don't think you mentioned which gdb build you use (or did you build it yourself?), but I wonder if [my build](https://github.com/ssbssa/gdb/releases) has the same problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243536/discussion-between-joshuacf-and-ssbssa).